# Create tick marks on a segment

Tags: metapost

The idea is to reproduce the figure such that point U has abscissa -5/7 and point P has root 13. My practice of Metapost is not sufficient to finish the figure.

[image]

```
  \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
  \usepackage{luatex85}
  \usepackage{luamplib}
  \begin{document}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
  \begin{mplibcode}
   beginfig(1);
        u  = 1.5cm;
        z0 = (0,0);
        z1 = (-2u,0);
        z2 = (4u,0);
        z3 = (u,0);
        z4 = (sqrt(13)*u,0);
        z5 = ((-5/7)*u,0);
        z6 = (0,-3*u);
        z7 = (2u,-3u);
        z8 = (2u,0);

        path q;
        q = unitsquare scaled 5;

        picture X;
        X = image(
        drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1.25 withcolor 1/4[blue, white]);
        draw (left--right) scaled 2;
        draw (down--up) scaled 2;
        drawoptions();
        );

        draw X shifted z0;
        draw X shifted z3;
        draw X shifted z4;
        draw X shifted z5;

        fill q rotated 180 shifted z8 withcolor 1/3[green, white];
        draw q rotated 180 shifted z8 ;

        fill q rotated -90 shifted z0 withcolor 1/3[green, white];
        draw q rotated -90 shifted z0 ;

        fill q rotated 90  shifted z7 withcolor 1/3[green, white];
        draw q rotated 90 shifted z7 ;

        fill q  shifted z6 withcolor 1/3[green, white];
        draw q  shifted z6 ;

        draw z0 -- z7 withcolor 1/2[red, white];

        draw z1 -- z2;
        path rectangle;
        rectangle = z0 -- z6 -- z7 -- z8 -- cycle;
        draw rectangle;

        label.lrt("$U$",z5);
        label.top("$O$",z0 + (0,3));
        label.top("$I$",z3 + (0,3));
        label.top("$P$",z4 + (0,3));
        label.lft("3",0.5[z0, z6]) withcolor 1/2[red, black];
        label.bot("2",0.5[z6, z7]) withcolor 1/2[red, black];
        label.bot("$-1$", (-u,0));

        path r;
        r = fullcircle scaled 7.211102551u;

        draw subpath (6.5, 8) of r;
        draw (-1)[z0, point 2.35 of rectangle] -- 1.8[z0, point 2.35 of rectangle]  withcolor 1/2[blue, white];
        
        pair A;
        A = fullcircle scaled 3.5cm intersectionpoint ((-0.8)[z0, point 2.35 of rectangle] -- 1.8[z0, point 2.35 of rectangle]);
       
        
        draw  (-2)[A, z5] -- 5[A, z5] withcolor red;
        draw  ((-2)[A, z5] -- 5[A, z5]) shifted ((-2/7)*cm,0) withcolor red;

                       
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear to me what you want to achieve. Aren't the coordinates for U and P already correct?

Comment: @Jasper Hello, my problem is not the positioning of the points P and Q whose abscissas were calculated with the theorems of Thales and Pythagoras but rather on how to draw the blue line and be able to divide it into seven equal segments.

Comment: I see. But then, I fear that you need to help me understand how the blue line and the two red lines in the reference picture are defined.

Comment: I don't know, but all you have to do is draw one arbitrarily.

Comment: My problem now is to create the seven tick marks on the blue segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?  (corrected)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
u  = 1.5cm;
z0 = (0,0);
z1 = (-2u,0);
z2 = (4u,0);
z3 = (u,0);
z4 = (sqrt(13)*u,0);
z5 = ((-5/7)*u,0);
z6 = (0,-3*u);
z7 = (2u,-3u);
z8 = (2u,0);

path q;
q = unitsquare scaled 5;

picture X;
X = image(
drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1.25 withcolor 1/4[blue, white]);
draw (left--right) scaled 2;
draw (down--up) scaled 2;
drawoptions();
);

draw X shifted z0;
draw X shifted z3;
draw X shifted z4;
draw X shifted z5;

fill q rotated 180 shifted z8 withcolor 1/3[green, white];
draw q rotated 180 shifted z8 ;

fill q rotated -90 shifted z0 withcolor 1/3[green, white];
draw q rotated -90 shifted z0 ;

fill q rotated 90  shifted z7 withcolor 1/3[green, white];
draw q rotated 90 shifted z7 ;

fill q  shifted z6 withcolor 1/3[green, white];
draw q  shifted z6 ;

draw z0 -- z7 withcolor 1/2[red, white];

draw z1 -- z2;
path rectangle;
rectangle = z0 -- z6 -- z7 -- z8 -- cycle;
draw rectangle;

label.lrt("$U$",z5);
label.top("$O$",z0 + (0,3));
label.top("$I$",z3 + (0,3));
label.top("$P$",z4 + (0,3));
label.lft("$3$",0.5[z0, z6]) withcolor 1/2[red, black];
label.bot("$2$",0.5[z6, z7]) withcolor 1/2[red, black];
label.llft("$-1$", (-u,0)) withcolor 1/2[red, black];

path r;
r = fullcircle scaled 7.211102551u;

draw subpath (6.5, 8) of r;
z9 = (-1)[z0, point 2.35 of rectangle];
z10 = 1.8[z0, point 2.35 of rectangle];
draw z9 -- z10  withcolor 1/2[blue, white];

pair A;
A = fullcircle scaled 3.5cm intersectionpoint ((-0.8)[z0, point 2.35 of rectangle] -- 1.8[z0, point 2.35 of rectangle]);

z11 = (-1)[A, z5];
z12 = 5[A, z5];

z13 = z11 shifted (2/7 u * left);  % <- 2/7 u not 2/7 cm!
z14 = z12 shifted (2/7 u * left);

draw z11 -- z12 withcolor red;
draw z13 -- z14 withcolor red;

z15 = whatever[z13, z14] = whatever[z9, z10];
path mark;  mark = (down -- up) scaled 2 rotated angle (z10-z9);
for i=0 upto 7:
    draw mark shifted (i/7)[z15, z0] withcolor 1/2[blue, white];
endfor

% alternative approach for equal ticks
picture ticks; ticks = image(
    draw (down--up) scaled 3/2 rotated -13 shifted 1/2 left withcolor red;
    draw (down--up) scaled 3/2 rotated -13 shifted 1/2 right withcolor red;
);
for i=1/2 upto 6+1/2:
    draw ticks rotated angle (z10-z9) shifted (i/7)[z15, z0];
endfor

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply but I thought the answer wouldn't come anymore. It's an amazing job you did, I learn a lot from your ideas and I read the document you wrote. Thanks a lot.